# Adding a new field to the product index

Tags: filters, product, commerce-cloud, indexing

I'm looking to add a new field to the list of indexed fields on the product index so I can use it as a filter. I haven't been able to find this option anywhere. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add fields to the list of indexed fields by going to Commerce Cloud > Merchant Tools > Search > Searchable Attributes. Once you add a new term you'll need to rebuild the index.